# How to add total per page (ex. Unit Cost) in Acumatica Report Designer?

Tags: acumatica

Just want to ask on how to add total per page of value (ex. Unit Cost).

Our client want to see total per page of Unit Cost whenever single transaction/PO Number returns more than 1 page.

P.S. Total per page not the whole total or grand total.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should work:

1. Ensure that you have at least one Page Header section in your report
2. To that Page Header add a variable named `PageTotal` (select the section, navigate to Variables in the section properties, press Add there) that would accumulate the total
3. Ensure that the variable has `=0` as the ValueExpr so that it is reset to 0 each time the Page Header section is evaluated
4. In your detail section add this same variable, but with a different ValueExpr - something like `=$PageTotal+[ARTran.CuryUnitPrice]` (replace `[ARTran.CuryUnitPrice]` with the field or variable that you're calculating the total of.
5. Add a PageFooter section and display a text box for your `PageTotal` variable there

Notes:

- The way this thing works: the report engine processes Page Header section and sets the variable to 0; then it processes details one after another and adds the desired values to your variable; once the page is done it will turn to the next one and process the Page Header section again resetting the total to 0.
- The name PageTotal is completely arbitrary - you may chose whichever you wish

Comment: Thank you sir. I'll try your solution.